# Compute recurrence relation p(m, n) = p(m-1, n-1) + p(m-1, n)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a recursive equation `p(m, n) = p(m-1, n-1) + p(m-1, n)`. I have to calculate `p(m, n)` for 1 ≤ m, n ≤ 10⁵. The problem is, for large values of m and n a recursive algorithm gives a time-out and memoization cannot be done due to huge memory requirements.

How should this problem be solved?
Base case: `p(1, n) = 1` and `p(n, 1) = n`

Comment: but you have to solve it recursively?

Comment: @Thomas not necessarily. I just want the value of p(m,n)

Comment: I don't really get the question.. can you print out the first calculation steps?

Comment: or show us what you have at the moment

Comment: @Thomas I forgot to add the base case. Please have a look at the edit

Comment: @Thomas For example p(8,4) = p(7,3) + p(7,4), now p(7,3) = p(6,2) + p(6,3) and so on... This takes a lot of time. One solution is storing the values in a 2d array but for n,m = 10^5, array initialization is not possible. So how to find out p(8,4)?

Comment: than you only go in y direction through the array... (the 7 never changes)

Comment: No, it will change. Look at the recursive equation

Comment: ohh jear I see. It looks like an exponential effort... maybe you can save every calculated value in a map, so you don't have to recalculate it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114186/discussion-between-aditya-and-thomas).

Comment: looks like you submit the code in online judge. it will help us to give you better solution (if not perfect) if you provide the code and problem link.

Comment: Is this a problem from a contest? If yes, can you provide a link to the original question? The problem statement is solving number of ways of  combining `r` items from `n` items. The full result will be too big. Modulo of the result makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with run-time complexity in **O(k)** by [summing over a row of binomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/a/208940) in [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle):

```js
function sumbincoef(n, k) {
  var bincoef = 1, sum = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
    bincoef = bincoef * (n - i + 1) / i;
    sum += bincoef;
  }
  return sum;
}

function p(m, n) {
  return sumbincoef(m - 1, n);
}

console.log(p(10000000, 50)); // 3.287546666914557e+285
```

The above result for `p(10000000, 50)` is the best possible 64-bit float representation for `3287546666914557308694953621332468056786361676360499868634585863380466725155646219866201991329567029752979948424340585220003362046032042304860695097308112596244670197867704848935084227060330672914092328758709997221191832805084217964476100165465190964311176563705979858704659291260737501` provided by JavaScripts `Number` datatype.

If you want the untruncated result, you could use the `BigNumber` datatype provided by `math.js` or e. g. use a language with built-in unlimited integer precision such as python:

```
def sumbincoef(n, k):
  bincoef = 1
  sum = 1
  for i in range(1, k + 1):
    bincoef = bincoef * (n - i + 1) / i
    sum += bincoef
  return sum

def p(m, n):
  return sumbincoef(m - 1, n)
```

The result for [`p(100000, 100000)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713114/retrieve-value-from-2-d-array#comment62921142_37716256) then computes as:

```
499501046507192253972016382165016795490214569527090845885764636931572916232128674163743665666224825201582197222777927465009399830382808828145423567712374643759944481493683554662317521368655623963290013926562054436854280264361419508228434551342533796175895734852642882234840076241617273777162514639326040347888548587055111602148817560266538899844896255830993538589288797776086004066014760230897461462964781196048289893677907933376274789865657240312463013091897065254029134301576756708936981141749544317887903105230331818606529389766117248600540424318477070091792567992901780178701093645407778329030359323063448641989731092113378967481944667862379438097956882838120556251035435243523258969819935505460018196737280904530080668894928014843179927901238072446652352611143006568854797917865974294924820228619193758535112116631671844721164869093886657664347210896806265095393445180183164158075136306996707640203558595746195167093746769722794815064609862820885861677177237577618965544613409120122637787604735232109297193143281637211566604237111077574665750135887503211441310591127467480027872866748233924163459047594797788458725483661220887021642022794105456895268782338606998831089263252858492741728124375916119162515932275273605718496708399083908512756140648903259740314770266957732873997064874959517425377216820725281582869800334669121365821701979006064013049210612375710391735611241570515203430185982008092787082821973612673247262485015725494504658113447637221435273821273612658375726059111572769418715411632110031651256876656468258217086260312807765589736930957145238072282746356420908759176566352648774768528071911978661396983651505303872842423871391609767461399191821808188237148477295333618456206816296606166782156794723260955094106191487045395819301161772547969438336820161478899695057607722400181860753455779555599800076529455386471051611521213101784674660802646378481292922291117729732263846155409865290314016325836822467188086620487667116664486514147958678463650664321165587980261524758583851658185476112847623020107169382759882200826407401117416594054877971098023823969426009927050867449297425550273462330861707156765496920296163447679326944348721350430351431775104278101477467624002539826078245984163255337205048391147597708080885877149876000494365368893810534294538548470580521901431197522266189479593538014463019674491305038744383642645905323424457194682453239229560580609665035395026852952109400642827970184953544401648343580582798061616599915546161254143309016094021972378649338104846790989219296398462506166346759734660386216776368278312411189391694403749963841581672015930223180935189489215651642191173520547215329573596417059548759261960616383719249528078184421646951972100130876548842530256646855072454319807081027802677366778496335047068763591457120361713396878253488278373796705065511267141504020453979366477210677565365102508579921211538023460486645364507080317698044027960117868844282392612004638855574456724620849780358589314921826698909043473705337555567676185577021829965544484874282940044393098746717896462310202588362300612530920200598314493633690153524918060898724233955037392317809733241461236806705756778358964589098402802686324207056417392912062956097730059220620467489148165852100126520933084748115936793032624270511110593477211189414459485604025728757068098240268486158228528249923976882858727406429870303866957938766617760780471795963759967550711112348150850685870966875245964768164755055764647591814140959591082583822797325791402449212805837407518390263393933135849982464847468852289743807331405546499101036850666516222550269268927559440173707409933255728966134245049650011836808427764708672102996268598262249896274157967185317198518590480573516153709349251752736114451358742516668416415014056645542084657522869496659196729664649747139800765487805935445946476422453712164238350312158558581136588330339805098390110228229450794976235237050057905548181686566469417843447470437966708845469390319929232365029446408799942223874306503157653438003504241863376389488867841502138945138605284191651073513986429766816605528203213195486228997484308145400980207087696788443829399621427495607586896213517162432420712372841944477094662072549375287970150662484877084847766514844010965243708175054896001810511938413758818499048880748981804835217407006206534178843995249871829814824785272976236769100018188516244749105166566645678115758492720520765852709696411736169942422677608660184404415605047197071746914110177482514076537554354930234061240148691281562249466598264810118630429325452515399665432600061583595759138287104784475656809204770606073689315552144885893072407915848292438347477741312625248061352235735611481013734118145490193873468849367947106272089617764919373991522512695489436673486630154877207823740273686636638362432637951749766817706347695022942749434178746393230762602040024505739294614454272167699849739043373580675989291928572821079158559650205899472039513417317877516994404336256394178864881324960691371828699646365111939628846211639274360064862769303598415189124153186294990424231925191417812920195865593634719073227682584503126501160879567154237760795073764957460764847218118345541661684688399656910463793501212311916560911835761838604920859385193008615426122402158816680137986658060063112416154266464449307727961071368925370548941112236475633178611278358488970488367077150864463416631753872560508393456066723284036989868635573095964996905908941377071089646344189514271545497122063025597292461895498316477513193285055744207113308148490503682635546425228973543075404702728889893215075244997931708235026411028139300443201285471622212702201712157010190603742876899950803323276049349039529467366012152531795368191076064030002091376466274262396395211786379928710477731618191546621412535575940088781686990576188099734313163527531754992562716693779730077045043100714681283686916584654116442716350074373831755941544258688763440976318008267295027808038385672680882772548721248953803195304665001420848242379701352333473424329681821271431262082241832608696129326423712247618165115265570672466616991116827580571573456595008524411341826295819986195631330807010285399836369176479873956274448070964363062987878085079632291177057596108862695982551717239684018452850190652827893315550573815659478577816825936387899595443144538274747600973746107442570853962617619714690085057474261950292217916487438463997079319232043863295087455246661942673271498962695028065578114412057359607906860506013369982431141580521514363436992016757106014975830542309658234403797226348262428503527722607627374672521742645899375609298682359523075770679129106952008605914785116376851369489389675345202246927679382525177857793643660079844253066557273855078784968772054874668705799559955748136340085901947545390152059220003779273428048848283479216281364166370820902229536392234002568038707714420635622817669181273453446821545103410837522990966087225668145692699157728030522984630225439385015209228957673914586288140531636105401791303045228623030960211879018157360007937453768081689262173114938495894390433572696442328620861175244388340193472673729441595379867764640035462073568534832351476535025354154570624638570238809672950365760311681711306406853725208126023672479870783944100192272338719447518959617229708562275511586949751517421096854404166485455408828050535434657901034753......(Stackoverflow wouldn't accept that many figures)......35584033065631459417382400319827381172596270290200128863975429530908663000094178338788124817542256133205278775822567235131041742740388086850961813203192415685921043738611547233989330610824844921161394624381302583949343237869506130180533962330864195008133672029951612013268171775150776491632259932940651971293308867493640115946272139008056659177138051629001196971303929378474742559650357926964921581983787765676242110637407432013648653577728554711716235928485261817836143275758132836194624040329639724476539354076803333370657299130399405639377328156503892871742094805404749559718018780537663179707071738441247346265393895346637645447954972532636035989709841370920409915283748844043118230409672811818851233907536566733098961559969558597989676416558748410250288649969283238492130407759470433388160427741579918094425224169955675752566454851995044459531566687902047443477947732956324052267310715147866687996449479664832222343450324337265830939410648597073095957066489336687641851497595353089962089070124678142503268136885818177784860001623498065332641225847583636580915696933779395639132466879020005529605686135419561759229854553740334926348040454590936489250787032272274132235539316693299556594405068873159492248372994505770167129657673870041055367409235760626687253635769065524148306489540738831634895697285178695268711384889816905784198111604201298512577652367194941554688
```

Comment: Well done ! I have tested your algorithm in python and it give the correct result a lot faster than my proposed algorithm.

Comment: @OlivierPellier-Cuit My thought process was actually similar to yours, by eliminating the obvious patterns. When I came back to this problem today, I realized that looking at the diagonal sequences e.g. `p(3,1), p(4,2), p(5,3), ...` is the key - big thanks to https://oeis.org by the way :)

Comment: @le_m I need to print the answer in modulo 10^9 + 7 as the values get very high. What necessary changes should I make to the code?

Comment: This is a typical requirement for competitive programming. Since we already gave you the solution, you should be able to figure that out yourself given that: 1. at least one term within the loop grows monotonically, 2. 10^9 + 7 is a prime and simplifies some modulo operations (might not be necessary in our case here)

Answer (score 0):

You can help the algorithm by giving more knowledge. In the following working example, i add some elements that make the algorithm a lot faster. You can of course add other knowledge or generalize existing one.
Note that generated number are very very huge.

```
def p(m,n):

  # p(1,n)=1
  if m == 1:
    return 1

  # p(m,1)=m
  if n == 1:
    return m

  # ===== START KNOWLEDGE ======  
  # p(n,m)=pow(2,m-1) if n>m-1
  if n > m-1:
    return pow(2,m-1)

  # p(n,m)=pow(2,m-2)-1 if n-m >2
  if n-m > 2:
    return pow(2,m-2)-1

  # p(n,m)=pow(2,m-1)-1 if abs(n-m)==2
  if abs(n-m) == 2:
    return pow(2,m-1)-1

  # p(n,m)=pow(2,m-1) if m-n=1
  if m-n==1:
    return pow(2, m-1)

  # p(n,m)=pow(2,m-1)-m if m-n==3
  if m-n == 3:
    return pow(2,m-1)-m

  # p(n,m)=pow(2,n*2) if (n+1)*2==m
  if (n+1)*2 == m:
    return pow(2, n*2)
  # ===== END KNOWLEDGE ======

  # general case
  return p(m-1, n-1)+p(m-1, n)
```

Comment: Could you suggest any faster method? Above one gives time-out.

Comment: Which tests values are you using and what is the time excepted ? It's very large values for example p(100000, 100000) is a number with 30103 digits (forget basic integer type and print out in the console).

Answer (score 0):

you also can use a one dimensional array. you don't have to save all results.

If you start to fill your one dimensional array, than m is equal to zero.
In the next step you calculate the row for m = 1 and save it into m = 0 arrayplace. for the next level you don't need the results below m-1 so you can replace them. You only have to remember how many iterations you did.

Comment: Time limit exceeds this way also. Any faster method?

Comment: shure... the calculation is like a triangle... so you only have to calculate the triangle values... you have to set the loops different borders. so you can half the calculationtime

Comment: can you pls post your code? into the question? maybe we find something